# regular expression adding text

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-match, regex-group

I am trying to extract a username from PJL print job.  I have got a regular expression what works, but I need to add text to the username.

The line that I am trying to edit is

@PJL SET USERNAME="john.wayne"

When I use this regular expression

@PJL\s+SET\s+USERNAME\s*=\s*"(\S+?)"

I get john.wayne but I am after adding some text before the name

e.g. Stack-john.wayne or overflow-john.wayne

It has to been in one line as that is what the program supports

https://www.papercut.com/products/ng/manual/applicationserver/topics/printer-external-usernames.html

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, please, edit your question and add some sample lines and expected result.

Comment: I have just added some more information.  Hopefully, it makes sense

Comment: You should add the information to the question, not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$string = '@PJL SET USERNAME="john.wayne"';
$string = preg_replace('/(@PJL\s+SET\s+USERNAME\s*=\s*")(\S+?")/', '$1text-$2', $string);
echo $string,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
@PJL SET USERNAME="text-john.wayne"
```